# How to tell which side of the curve represents the equation $y=\sec^{-1} x$ and which represents $y=-\sec^{-1} x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, volume

If we have the $y=\sec^{-1}x$ and we want to rewrite it as $x=\sec y$ for the purpose of finding the volume using the cylindrical shell technique due to the revolution of the region bounded by $y=\sec^{-1}x$ and $x=2$ about $x=-1$.

Now to calculate the volume of this curve we will have to know the equation of the curve in the $1^{st}$ quad (the one below) so how do I generally find whether it's positive or negative?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although  not sketched, the curve has both positive and negative branches symmetric to x-axis which becomes positive in squaring for volume in $\int \pi y^2 dx$. The closed area to the left of thicker line is required to be swept out.

For convenience to find volume interchange the axes and shift along new displaced $y$ axis  by 1 unit. $x$ limits are $\pm \sec^{-1}2$

$$ V= \pi \int_{{-\sec^{-1}2}}^{\sec^{-1}2} (1+ \sec x)^2 dx $$

So $V$ is addition of indefinite integrals

$$\int dx,\; \int \sec^2x\; dx,\;\int 2 \sec x . $$

Comment: I don't want the solution of this problem, I know it's easier to use the washer technique. I'm asking this generally as some problems it might be more difficult to use this technique for example if we wanted the volume due to revolution of the region bounded between $y=sec^{-1}x$ and $x=(y+1)^2$ about x=-1 for example

Comment: Edited answer  up to what I understood.

Comment: The cylindrical shell technique is when you take a rectangle of infinitesimal thickness parallel to the axis of rotation and integrate and use the formula $V=\int_a^b 2\pi r h dr$ so in my example it would be $\int_1^2 2\pi (1+x)(sec^{-1}x)dx$ my question is whether it will be $\int_1^2 2\pi (1+x)(sec^{-1}x)dx$ or $\int_1^2 2\pi (1+x)(-sec^{-1}x)dx$